# Hashed assets on multi-site Rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Rails: 4.2.7.1, Ruby: 2.3.1

We used to use non-hashed assets for serving our assets on our multi-site application by hardcoding the path to the asset in the individual site's headers. We are now pre-compiling hashed assets with Sprockets on each deploy in production with these settings:

**production.rb**

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_files = true
config.assets.prefix = "/assets"
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```

We end up with hashed assets, for example, in /public/assets/skins/site1/skin-70ee38249235f8521a243a8f955ed08c.css.

We have a skin file for each path that we use to load our styles per site. We do generate a site application.css that remains unused. Each skin file contains variables for each site and then imports the site's manifest file containing the sass stylesheets.

What we tried to do was create a way for our CMS to look for the hashed asset:

```
stylesheet_link_tag("/assets/skins/site1/skin.css", media: "all")
```

The issue is that the site is still looking for the non-hashed skin file. If we have the plain skin.css, it will work.

Same goes for Javascript:

```
javascript_include_tag "/assets/admin.js"
```

It will look for the non-hashed asset, even though the hashed asset is present. I tried to remove the "/assets" part from the link tags and it will fail.

Is there a setting that we are missing to have Rails look for the proper hashed asset? Any advice is appreciated.